# OpenSSH Public Key to PPK file

Tags: ssh, putty, openssh, ppk

I am trying to convert an openSSH public key .txt file into a .ppk file using puttygen. I keep getting an error. I'm confused on how to do this.

Error I keep getting: The error is "Could not load private key (Not a recognized key file format)"

The .txt file has ssh-rsa at the beginning

The .pub file has the below as a header

---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----

Comment: ""

What do I need to do (or point me to a resource) to get this converted to a ppk file.

Thank you

Comment: You say you keep getting an error? Exactly what error are you getting?

Comment: .ppk files contain a private-public keypair, you would need both to create one

Comment: @Kenster The error is "Could not load private key (Not a valid key format)"

Comment: @Kenster Sorry the error is "Could not load private key (Not a recognized key file format)"

Comment: As @heavyd mentioned, you need both the public and private key pair to create a PuTTY public+private key file [`.ppk`] - the OpenSSH private key will begin `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`, and the public key `ssh-<algorithm>`